# How can i continue to generate this series (xyz*3)==zzz after 9999

Tags: java, numberformatexception

This code generates (xyz+xyz+xyz=zzz series for 0 to 9999). If I try to go past 9999, I am getting a `NumberFormatException`.

**Code:**

```
//package com.uttara.todo;

public class Addition {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x=1;
        int y=1;
        int z=1;
        for( x=1;x<9999;x++)//this works fine till 999 at 9999 throws numberformat exception
        {
            for( y=1;y<9999;y++)
            {
                for( z=1;z<9999;z++)
                {
                    String str=""+x+y+z;
                    String str1=""+z+z+z;

                    **int temp=Integer.parseInt(str);//this throws exception**
                    int temp1=Integer.parseInt(str1);
                    //temp=temp*3;
                    //System.out.println(temp);
                    if((temp*3)==temp1)
                        System.out.println(temp);
                        //break;

                    //x++;
                }
            }
            x++;
        }
        y++;


        //System.out.println("x="+x+"y="+y+"z="+z);
    }
}
```

**And the error I am getting:**

> number format exception at 100010001000

Comment: Probably you should research the range of the different types such as int or long. Hint: none of these types can represent arbitrary large numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Each type has its limits, so an integer in Java is between
-2^31 = -2147483648  and 2^31-1 = 2147483647

So as soon as you build a string with a number outside this area, you will receive this exception.

You could choose a different type. The next possible type you could use is Long:
Long.MAX_VALUE =  9223372036854775807
Long.MIN_VALUE = -9223372036854775808

Comment: And I also want to mention BigInteger: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

That class does not have a primitive type behind it, so you have to change more than just replacing some types. So parsing a BigInteger is done inside the constructor and to multiply two BigInteger, you need to use the BigInteger.multiply function and the 3 must be a BigInteger.